# Xcode iOS simulator displays black borders on top and bottom of views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is a fresh project created under the Game template in newest version of Xcode. The view is acting really weird, look at the image:
[image]

Of course, there's no constraints. If I add alignment constraints and align it correctly to horizontal and vertical center, it's aligned correctly. When normal constraints are added for each side, I get `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`

My main problem is however these black borders. Why do they appear? (Have tried iPhone 12, 11 and SE 2 emulators)

Comment: Is the Xcode 12.4 version? I have faced many, many issues with this version of Xcode. For example, my projects won't open if I launch Xcode; so to fix that, I have been opening my projects from the Finder. As an answer to your problem, I would suggest you to try other templates, change the simulators, maybe to open/create a new project. In one word, just keep figuring out, trying other methods. I think it will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Game template does not include a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` -- no idea why.

If you add one to your project and set it in the project settings:

[image]

You'll have a full-screen view as expected.

Comment: Thanks, got my project fixed after re-selecting LaunchScreen in a regular iOS app template.

Comment: You are right, In my case, it was working fine. I think it is appearing only on Xcode12.5
When I update my Xcode to 13+, it disappeared without changing these settings.

Answer (score 3):

I was just having this exact issue, but instead of using UIKit and Storyboard, I'm using SwiftUI (Xcode 14.1 and iOS 16). @DonMag's answer is still roughly the solution, but the project settings you have to adjust are slightly different with SwiftUI. Under Build Settings, set the `Launch Screen (Generation)` plist key to "Yes".

Comment: The accepted answer works, but this is the simpler answer with the latest versions of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! This answer works with XCode 14.2